# Looping back to first record in array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm writing a programme that will display messages that are stored in an array one at a time. I want it to be able to move through them one at a time upon command from the user. My problem is when it reaches the last value on the array I cannot figure out a way to get it to loop back to the first record.

I appreciate that this problem may seem obvious to some but I have struggled to come up with a solution. I would really appreciate if someone could show me a way to solve this.

Comment: Can you post your attempt at solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must work.

```
import sys

array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

x = 0
count = 0

while x == 0:
    user_input = int(input("Enter 1 to move in array or 2 to exit: "))

    if user_input == 1 and count < len(array):
        print(array[count])
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = 0

    if user_input == 2:
        x = 1
```

Comment: Upd. Exit option to end while